# Mock grpc service in unit testing nestjs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, nestjs, grpc

I want write an unit test for my `getAllGroups()` method in **mail.service.ts**:

```
public async getAllGroup(): Promise<{ id: number, name: string }[]> {
  try {
    return (await lastValueFrom(this.groupService.GetAllGroup({}))).groups;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

The problem is i want to mock `GetAllGroups()` that is a grpc method and fetch datas.
how i add groupService in **mail.service.ts**:

```
constructor(
  @Inject('groupService') private groupClient: ClientGrpc,
) { }
private readonly groupService = this.groupClient.getService<GroupService>('groupService');
```

In **mail.service.spec.ts** how i provide groupService:

```
{
   provide: 'groupService',
   useValue: createMock<ClientGrpc>()
             .getService<GroupService>('groupService')
}
```

And the test i write for `getAllGroups()` method:

```
it(`getAllGroup() should return list of gropus`, async () => {
    const groupMock = createMock<MailService>();
    groupMock.GetAllGroup.mockReturnValue( of({ groups: [{ id: 123, name: "abc" }] }));

    expect(service.getAllGroup()).toEqual([
        { id: 123, name: "abc" }
    ]);
})
```

After test execution its failed and return this:

```
Expected: [{"id": 123, "name": "abc"}]
Received: {}

  56 |         groupMock.GetAllGroup.mockReturnValue( of({ groups: [{ id: 123, name: "abc" }] }));
  57 |
> 58 |         expect(service.getAllGroup()).toEqual([
     |                                       ^
  59 |             { id: 123, name: "abc" }
  60 |         ]);
  61 |     })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem ...
I should use await before `service.getAllGroup()` Like this:

```
expect(await service.getAllGroup()).toEqual([
    { id: 123, name: "abc" }
]);
```